# PHP readfile(); and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using `readfile();` to start a download and it works perfectly fine but when try to using JavaScript to check if the user can download the file it doesn't start the download it instead shows the binary code of the file. I want it to download the file.

I use this to check if the user can download the file:

```
http.open("GET", "includes/checkdownload.php", true);
```

In the `checkdownload.php` I have this

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("file.pdf");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't start a download as such with an Ajax request. You can check the availability of the file with an Ajax request (and you should probably use HEAD for large files to avoid downloading the whole thing) but you'll need to use `window.open` to actually open a save file dialog.

```
window.open('includes/checkdownload.php');
```

Or, as @Derek points out, you can use an `<iframe>`, or you can redirect by setting `window.location.href`, or you could use `window.showModalDialog` too. Anything that will open that URL somewhere in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a proxy script that will tell you if the file is valid. So instead of doing an http.open on the file, you call a script on the server that will return you an assertion if the file can be downloaded or not.

For example:

```
$.get('includes/candownload.php', function(data){ 
    if(data == 'ok'){
        window.location.href = "includes/checkdownload.php";
    }else{
        alert('Cannot download your file');
    }
)
```

And in your php file "candownload.php"

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
ob_clean();
flush();
if(file_exists("file.pdf")){ echo 'ok'; }else{ echo 'no'; }
```

Comment: I replaced the http.open with window.location.href and it works but it redirects to the checkdownload.php can I stop the redirect?

Comment: You need to read and understand what we are saying and what you are doing to solve the problem, we can't help you more than that if you just speed through the process and assume something will be right... good lucj